# Converting CSV files to Excel workbook via Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, excel-online

hope you're all doing good.

I created a form with PowerApps. On this form i have a button that i can use to convert the content of my form into a CSV file (in reality, it's a tabbed form so the flow i use creates many CSV files - one per tab).  I then need those CSV file to be converted into XLSX workbooks so i can then consolidate the results into one general workbook.

I found [this post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/convert-csv) that explains how to do what i want to....and it works except for that the final workbook is not formatted into rows but...everything is on 1 single row.

so my CSV file (resulting in the conversion of the form via my flow) comes formatted like this :

[image]

and when i follow the post, everything seems to be good except the fact that i end up with an XLSX file formatted this way :

[image]

Would someone be able to help me with this please ?

Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: sorry but the "Hello" in my message doesn't show up :-P